# Confusion with SCK MOSI timing relationship in SPI

Tags: spi

I have a confusion correlating SCK and MOSI.
Below is an example timing diagram of SCK and MOSI timing diagrams for an SPI:

[image]

My first confusion is that: if the MOSI above is varying much faster than SCK, wouldn't that be a problem since the peripheral will read each bit at rising edge of SCK?

Secondly, when does MOSI outputs a bit? I thought it outputs at each SCK rising edge, but that doesn't match the above diagrams either. Because the green is varying before the consecutive SCK rising edge.

Comment: This timing diagram might clarify a bit: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/SPI_timing_diagram2.svg/400px-SPI_timing_diagram2.svg.png

Comment: As seen in the link above, SPI has four configuration modes. Polarity determines the clock polarity. Phase determines whether data is changed or captured on the first clock edge.

Comment: Isn't the peripheral reading each bit at rising edge of SCK? But MOSI bits can change many times before the next SCK rising edge. And  if SCK and MOSI were synchronous, wouldn't that mean MOSI would  change at the each rising edge of SCK? That doesn't match the diagram in question either.

Comment: @pnatk [] Again, SPI does not have a standardized edge/phase, you can set the clock polarity (commonly called CPOL) and the clock phase (commonly called CPHA) and thereby get 4 different setups. Getting these clock settings wrong between master and slave is perhaps also the far the most common problem in SPI communication. "But MOSI bits can change many times before the next SCK rising edge." No they can't. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Is the period of 1-bit MOSI same with the period of SCK?

Answer (score 1):

> *My first confusion is that: if the MOSI above is varying much faster
> than SCK, wouldn't that be a problem since the peripheral will read
> each bit at rising edge of SCK?*

The whole point about SPI is that MOSI is synchronous with the clock SCK.

> *Secondly, when does MOSI outputs a bit?*

There are several variants of SPI and one example is that MOSI changes state on the rising edge of the CLK signal and the slave reads MOSI on the falling edge of SCK thus the slave reads clean stable data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the thing I dont get is that if SCK and MOSI is synchronous, wouldn't that mean MOSI should change at the each rising edge of SCK? And if so, that doesn't match the diagram in my question. MOSI is changing between rising edges of SCK. I hope I could clarify where Im stuck at. I didnt downvote btw.

Comment: @pnatk "synchronous" doesn't mean it has to change on rising edges only; it can change on falling edges and be synchronous too. But, whatever edge is used to refresh the MOSI output, it has to be the opposite edge used by the slave when reading the MOSI.

Answer (score -1):

SPI data transfer is synchronous to the SPI bus clock SCK.

Synchronous to SCK means the timing is controlled by the SCK activity. Bus master and target device derive their data transfer timing from SCK. Synchronous to SCK does not mean that MOSI and MISO must change exactly on an SCK edge.

During transfer, once per SCK the master device and target device both:

- Send out one bit on their data output
- Sample their data input to receive one bit

So both the master and the target can have a serial transmitter and a serial receiver. Some devices have both, some only one - it depends what's needed by that IC.

In a clock-synchronous data transfer the data is:

- Set up by the transmitter away from the receiver's sampling clock edge
- Sampled by the receiver on/around its sampling clock edge

This is [shown below](https://developer.electricimp.com/resources/spi).

[image]

There are different modes of operation that set:

- On which edge the transmitter can sample its input data
- On which edge the target can can sample its input data

SPI is a broad specification and the exact implementation and signal timing depends on the implementation. What will actually happen on a particular bus is a combination of:

- The timing specifications and behaviour of the master and target devices
- The propagation delays of interconnecting wires/tracks and any circuitry

I have designed FPGA-controlled SPI bus masters and targets that use other bus timing and activity because of slow interconnecting circuitry with varying timing. The important thing is that the bus timing is kept at something the master and target devices can work reliably at.

(*There are corner cases at data transfer start and end, different variants of SPI such as QSPI, and so on. I'm not mentioning those because this is an answer to the question, not an SPI reference text, and it'll muddy a simple overview.*)

Comment: Im stuck with some points. Is the period of 1-bit MOSI same with the period of SCK?

Comment: @pnatk, usually and roughly, yes. Please gather all your points into one comment rather than run a protracted Q&A session.

Comment: So is it deliberate that start of MOSI always leading the rising edge of SCK? Is there a logic behind it?

Comment: I mean why they are not in phase (MOSI bit and SCK)

Comment: @pnatk, this site is not a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site so you write a clear question and you get single answers. Nor is it a personal tutorial, a substitute for learning through existing published material. There is a clear logic. And it's all written up very well already, you'll find it on the Internet.